# phone number to lat/long on iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

i was just wandering whether its even possible to get the latitude and longitude based on telephone number so that i can show them on iphone??

Comment: The technical term for this is "tracing" and it's absolutely possible...  As long as you have police powers OR are seriously in bed with a telco.  Regardless, you're not going to find it in the iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of such a thing, but assuming that you can reverse the number to an address you could geocode it to lat/long.  I wouldn't expect to be able to reliably reverse phone numbers to address though.

Comment: reverse the number to an address?? how to do that?? and what if user is moving ?? is that address static?

Comment: That's the tricky part.  You'll need to find some sort of phonebook service to get that info. I don't know of any, and I would be very surprised if you found one that had any decent level of coverage. (The only real authoritative source is the phone companies and they don't just give that info out for free if at all)